# Periodically running a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, web-scraping

I have the following function that gets some data from a web page and stores in a dictionary. The time stamp as a key, and the data (list) as value.

```
def getData(d):

    page = requests.get('http://www.transportburgas.bg/bg/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find_all("table", class_="table table-striped table-hover")
    rows = table[0].find_all('tr')

    table_head = table[0].find_all('th')
    header = []
    tr_l = []

    rows = []
    for tr in table[0].find_all('tr'):
        value = tr.get_text()
        rows.append(value)

    time_stamp = rows[1].split("\n")[1]
    data = []
    for i in rows[1:]:
        a = i.split("\n")
        if time.strptime(a[1], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')[:4] == time.localtime()[:4]:
            data.append(int(a[3]))
        else:
            data.append(np.nan)

    d[time_stamp] = data
```

The data on the web page gets updated every 5 mins. I would like to make the function run automatically every 5 min. I am trying to do it with the time.sleep and this function:

```
def period_fun(it):
    iterations = it 
    while iterations != 0:
        getData(dic)
        time.sleep(300)
        iterations = iterations -1
```

However, this function runs only once and I end up with only one item in the dictionary. I have tried it with a simple print (1) instead of the function and it works (1 gets printed several times), but when I implement it with the function it doesn't work.

Would really appreciate any suggestions on the functions or how I could achieve my goal!

Best regards, 
Mladen

Comment: Have you tried using cron?

Comment: You can use a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object for invoking functions periodically.

Answer (score 0):

How about using some library which use cron jobs?

Schedule looks nice although it is not using cron like syntax: https://github.com/dbader/schedule